# Keeping TextBlocks positioned at scaled line endpoints when window is resized

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm using a grid to center a scaled line within a window when the window is resized. I would like to attach two Textblocks; one at each endpoint of the line. When the window is resized, I would like the size (and fontsize) of the Textblock to remain unchanged. I would like to transform the canvas similar to how the line geometry is transformed so the TextBlocks track the endpoints of the line when the window is resized. How can I do this?

Chart.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Chart"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Name="chartWindow">
<Grid x:Name="chartGrid" SizeChanged="ChartGrid_SizeChanged" Background="Black" ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ScaleTransform x:Key="transform"
                    CenterX="0"
                    CenterY="0"
                    ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=chartWindow, Path=ScaleValue}"
                    ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=chartWindow, Path=ScaleValue}" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Path Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Visible"
          Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Path.Data>
            <GeometryGroup Transform="{StaticResource transform}">
                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0.1,0.1" EndPoint="0.5,0.5"/>
            </GeometryGroup>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>

    <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Visible">
        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" 
                   Foreground="White" FontSize="12"
                   Text="P1" >
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="90" Canvas.Top="90"
                   Foreground="White" FontSize="12"
                   Text="P2" >
        </TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Chart.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
public partial class Chart : Window
{
    public Chart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ScaleValue = 100;
    }

    #region ScaleValue Depdency Property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ScaleValue", typeof(double), typeof(Chart), new UIPropertyMetadata(1.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnScaleValueChanged), new CoerceValueCallback(OnCoerceScaleValue)));

    private static object OnCoerceScaleValue(DependencyObject o, object value)
    {
        Chart mainWindow = o as Chart;
        if (mainWindow != null)
            return mainWindow.OnCoerceScaleValue((double)value);
        else
            return value;
    }

    private static void OnScaleValueChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Chart mainWindow = o as Chart;
        if (mainWindow != null)
            mainWindow.OnScaleValueChanged((double)e.OldValue, (double)e.NewValue);
    }

    protected virtual double OnCoerceScaleValue(double value)
    {
        if (double.IsNaN(value))
            return 1.0d;

        value = Math.Max(0.1, value);
        return value;
    }

    protected virtual void OnScaleValueChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
    {

    }

    public double ScaleValue
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(ScaleValueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ScaleValueProperty, value);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private void ChartGrid_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CalculateScale();
    }

    private void CalculateScale()
    {
        double yScale = ActualHeight;
        double xScale = ActualWidth;
        double value = Math.Min(xScale, yScale);
        ScaleValue = (double)OnCoerceScaleValue(chartGrid, value);
    }
}
}
```

I worked on a solution that seems appropriate. The TextBlocks are placed on a canvas and each label lives in its own grid which the zeroth and 2nd row and column definitions are ratioed. To set the ratio just use the formula: (1/0.1)-1=9 and set this as the star multiplier.

Revised Chart.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Chart"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Name="chartWindow">
<Grid x:Name="chartGrid" SizeChanged="ChartGrid_SizeChanged" Background="Black" ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ScaleTransform x:Key="transform"
                    CenterX="0"
                    CenterY="0"
                    ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=chartWindow, Path=ScaleValue}"
                    ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=chartWindow, Path=ScaleValue}" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Path Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Visible"
          Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Path.Data>
            <GeometryGroup Transform="{StaticResource transform}">
                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0.1,0.1" EndPoint="0.3,0.2"/>
            </GeometryGroup>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Visible">
        <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=chartWindow, Path=ScaleValue}" Height="{Binding ElementName=chartWindow, Path=ScaleValue}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="White" FontSize="12" Text="P1"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=chartWindow, Path=ScaleValue}" Height="{Binding ElementName=chartWindow, Path=ScaleValue}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2.333*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="White" FontSize="12" Text="P2"/>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

This purely XAML solution will help you. You just need to bind the column width and row height to the start/end points of your path. In this code I only used a rectangle to demonstrate the idea. But if you are using a Path, you will have to create a multi value converter to convert Height and Width of the expanding cell to create new path points. No other codebehind will be needed to create this GUI.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ExpandingColumn" Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width= "{Binding ExpandingColumn.Width}" Height="2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
            Foreground="Black" FontSize="12"
            Text="P1" >
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"
               Foreground="Black" FontSize="12"
               Text="P2" >
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Not quite what I want. I don't want to be hardcoding numbers (i.e. "30") into the XAML.The solution does handle vertical and horizontal placements though.

Comment: 30 was just the spacing value and its hard coded for simplicity. If you dont want it to be hard coded to xaml, you can bind it to some variable in view model